# Run-Time Check Failure #3 - The variable 'pLib' is being used without being initialized

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I am perplexed as to why i'm getting this error. The code is below. I'm getting the error at this line "if (pLib->m_fAbortThread)"

```
UINT CLibary:: WorkerThread(LPVOID pArgs)
{
    CLibrary *pLib = CLibrary::GetInstance();
    if ( !pLib  )
    {
      return ED_NOLIBOBJECT;
    }

    while (1)
    {
       if (pLib->m_fAbortThread)
       {
          //Do Something here
       }
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is `m_fAbortThread` guarded using critical section?

Comment: @AndrewKomiagin No, it's not.

Comment: Use `CEvent::SetEvent()` and `WaitForSingleObject` instead of Boolean flags to tell the thread to exit.

Comment: Also your main thread should wait for the child thread to exit using `WaitForSingleObject` to prevent race condition.

Comment: I'd say the reasonable guess is that pLib->m_fAbortThread *really is uninitialized*. Can you post the code for CLibrary::GetInstance()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Andrew's comments (although 100% correct) do not explain this "Run-Time Check Failure #3".

When this check is enabled, the compiler reserves some memory on the stack to track initialization of local variables. It literally writes 0 into a byte corresponding to some variable in prologue and 1 when this variable is assigned some value.

Then the Run-Time Check compares that value to 0 and issues an alert (`call __RTC_UninitUse`) if it is.

So for that check to fail, you need to write zeroes into your function's stack. The code that does that is obviously not posted in your question.